# How to have Sanic respond with http and ws?

Tags: python, websocket, sanic

I have the following code for a Sanic hello world based off combining different endpoints here:

- https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/response.html
- https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/websocket.html

Code is:

```
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic import response
from sanic.websocket import WebSocketProtocol

app = Sanic()

@app.route("/")
async def test(request):
    return response.json({"hello": "world"})


@app.route('/html')
async def handle_request(request):
    return response.html('<p>Hello world!</p>')

@app.websocket('/feed')
async def feed(request, ws):
    while True:
        data = 'hello!'
        print('Sending: ' + data)
        await ws.send(data)
        data = await ws.recv()
        print('Received: ' + data)

@app.route('/html2')
async def handle_request(request):
  return response.html("""<html><head><script>
         var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("wss://0.0.0.0:8000/feed",      "protocolOne");
         exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
         console.log(event.data)};</script></head><body><h1>Hello socket!</h1><p>hello</p></body></html>""")

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
# app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, protocol=WebSocketProtocol)    # ws
```

The routes "/" and "/html" work fine, but

```
http://0.0.0.0:8000/feed
```

produces:

```
Error: Invalid websocket request
```

and "/html2" renders the page fine, but doesn't log to console, showing in the debugger:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://0.0.0.0:8000/feed.
```

What should I change or add to make a viable websocket endpoint that plays nicely with the http ones, too?

Comment: Try using non secure web socket protocol: `ws://`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using 0.0.0.0 as your endpoint within your client html doesn't make any sense and you're not using SSL so you want to use ws:// rather than wss://.  In other words,

```
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic import response
from sanic.websocket import WebSocketProtocol

app = Sanic()

@app.websocket('/feed')
async def feed(request, ws):
    while True:
        data = 'hello!'
        print('Sending: ' + data)
        await ws.send(data)
        data = await ws.recv()
        print('Received: ' + data)

@app.route('/html2')
async def handle_request(request):
  return response.html("""<html><head><script>
         var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.host + '/feed');
         exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
         console.log(event.data)};</script></head><body><h1>Hello socket!</h1><p>hello</p></body></html>""")

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Comment: Why does "Using 0.0.0.0 as your endpoint within your client html" not make any sense?

Comment: @Mittenchops - 0.0.0.0 only makes sense on the server side.  It basically means accept connections on all interfaces.  The client needs to know where to connect to the server.  0.0.0.0 isn't a routable endpoint from the client standpoint.